# Cakephp email error

Tags: cakephp

My controller

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email'); //before class begins

//function
public function contact(){

        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $email->config('smtp');
        $email->from('me@gmail.com');
        $email->to('you@gmail.com');
        $email->subject('About');
        $email->send('My message');
    }

//Email.php in config folder

class EmailConfig {

    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => 'me@gmail.com',
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        //'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'me@gmail.com',
        'password' => '*****',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => false,
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    ); 
}
```

The error i get is

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\wamp\www\myproject\lib\Cake\Network\CakeSocket.php on line 222

what do i need to change?

I even created the view file in Views/Users/contact.

Do i need to change the view file in View/Email folder?

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase max_execution_time variable in your php.ini file.

You shouldn't be timing out sending an email through gmail though. Have you configured the smtp options correctly?

from the cake book
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

'You can configure SSL SMTP servers, like GMail. To do so, put the 'ssl://' at prefix in the host and configure the port value accordingly. Example:'

```
<?php
class EmailConfig {
    public $gmail = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: Increased the time as well but still can't send the email. It gives me the same error. What am I missing out here?

Comment: Yes I did follow the basic steps from cook book.If I follow them it says Could not send email, Internal error has occurred.  If I use 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com' it  says ssl is not configured.

Comment: Stack Trace     CORE\Cake\Network\Email\CakeEmail.php line 972 → MailTransport->send(CakeEmail)
APP\Controller\UsersController.php line 103 → CakeEmail->send(string)
[internal function] → UsersController->contact()
CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php line 485 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(UsersController, array)
CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 103 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 85 → Dispatcher->_invoke(UsersController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP\webroot\index.php line 92 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)

Comment: It's a stack trace error.I posted all errors on that page.Do I need to upload the project in order to send email?

Comment: No just install and enable openssl

Comment: I'm sorry for being a total noob but I don't know how to do that.I changed it in the php.ini file.Is it right?

Comment: Wamp should allow you to enable it, but yes look for the extension called openssl and uncomment the line

Comment: Yeah. I uncommented that line but still no change.

Comment: so the host is the ssl:// address and you have restarted wamp since uncommenting the extension?

Comment: yep.even restarted the pc just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$email->from('me@gmail.com');` from your action and try again. Specify *From* address only in the email config. Then see whether it works.

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email'); //before class begins

//function
public function contact(){

        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $email->config('smtp');
        $email->to('you@gmail.com');
        $email->subject('About');
        $email->send('My message');
    }

//Email.php in config folder

class EmailConfig {

    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => 'me@gmail.com',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 60,
        'username' => 'me@gmail.com',
        'password' => '*****',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => false,
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    ); 
}
```